# Cocaine gem locked at 0.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I am trying to use Paperclip on my web app and get this issue when uploading a fil

```
Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
```

So I tried to specify which version of cocaine to install as per other answers on Stack Overflow. Doing so gave me this result:

```
The bundle currently has cocaine locked at 0.5.1.
Try running `bundle update cocaine'
```

and now when I try boot the local server it fails. Running `bundle update cocaine` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running 'sudo bundle update cocaine'? This should give you a trace of what the conflicts are. 
If you have no luck there I would recommend deleting the Gemfile.lock file and re-running bundle install. If that doesn't work please post your Gemfile and maybe we can identify the issue.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the help. I deleted the Gemfile.lock and ran 'bundle install' fixing the problem.